# Leaflet.Draw options - dynamically changing polyline color

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-draw

I am playing around with the Leaflet.Draw plugin and its options. What I try to do is dynamically setting the color option for the polyline to a variable like this:

```
let options = {
    position: 'topright',
    draw: {
        polyline: {
            shapeOptions: {
                color: penColor,
                weight: 15
            }
        }
    },
    edit: {
        featureGroup: drawnItems,
        remove: true
    }
};
```

Unfortunately when changing the penColor variable after the page loads the color does not. Is there a way to change  polyline color after the plugin has loaded, like rereading the options on a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to change it's properties after draw control is created, but not through the change of the variable that was used when creating the control. At the time of the creation of the control, property is evaluated and used as a value, not as variable.

You can change option value through the properties of the control. In your case that could look something like:

```
drawControl.options.draw.polyline.shapeOptions.color = '#0000FF';
```

Comment: Works almost perfect, thank you. I had to wrap it in a function like this:

map.on('draw:drawstart', function() {
    drawControl.options.draw.polyline.shapeOptions.color = penColor;
});

and when finnshed a drawing a new polyline it changes to the new color instead. Now I just need to change the color while drawing :-)

Comment: This is going to be much harder, if possible at all. Good luck!